# Ionic2: getting input text field in a page by a component

Tags: ionic2

This is my search `page` where I load results with a for cycle

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title>Search</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding> 
<ion-list>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-input [(ngModel)]="room_name" type="text"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-list> 
        <guide-view *ngFor="let g of guideList" [guide]="g"></guide-view> 
    </ion-list> 
</ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

My goal is to make available the `[(ngModel)]="room_name"` for the `guideView` components:

```
@Component({ 
    selector: 'guide-view', 
    template: ` 
<ion-item> 
    <ion-thumbnail item-left> 
      <img src="{{guide.imagePreviewUrl}}"> 
    </ion-thumbnail> 
    <h2>{{guide.username}} {{message}}</h2> 
    <p>rate: {{guide.rate}}</p>
    <button clear ion-button outline item-right icon-left (click)="engageGuide(guide.username)">
        <ion-icon name="arrow-dropright"></ion-icon>
        Open Room
    </button>
</ion-item>` 
})
export class GuideView { 
    @Input() 
    guide: Guide;
    message : any;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public myService: MyServiceh) {}    

    engageGuide(guide: Guide): void{ 
        this.myService.openRoom(???room_name???,guide).subscribe((data)=>{
        ....
    } 
}
```

As you can see I need the value of that input text, for call `openRoom` but I don't know how to take it.

Answer (score 0):

In the search page this row

`<guide-view *ngFor="let g of guideList" [guide]="g"></guide-view>`

becomes

`<guide-view *ngFor="let g of guideList" [guide]="g" [room_name]="room_name"></guide-view>`

Then I can take in the compoment the `room_name` with the following code:

```
export class GuideView { 
    @Input() 
    guide: Guide;
    message : any;
    @Input('room_name') = myRoom;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public myService: MyServiceh) {}    

    engageGuide(guide: Guide): void{ 
        this.myService.openRoom(this.myRoom,guide).subscribe((data)=>{
        ....
    } 
}
```